# How to add level 0 columns in multi-index data frame and keep format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, calculated-columns

I have a large multi-indexed data frame with many rows and columns. I want to add a column to the data frame at level one, while keeping the level two structure. My first goal is to understand how to add a new blank column to this data frame. My second goal is to understand how to populate that new column with a calculation, in this case a simple subtraction between the first column fields and second column fields.

Original Data frame:

```
data = [[99,3,12,4,63,55]]

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1. FY21','2. FY22','3. FY23'],['Values','Sites']])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)

df.columns.set_levels(['1. FY21','2. FY22','3. FY23'],level=0,inplace=True)
df.columns.set_levels(['Values', 'Sites'], level=1, inplace=True)
```

[image]

Desired Output #1 - Adding just an empty new column

```
data_new = [[99,3,12,4,63,55,"blank","blank"]]

cols_new = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1. FY21','2. FY22','3. FY23','4. New Column'],['Values','Sites']])

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data_new, columns = cols_new)
```

[image]

Desired Output #2 - Doing a calculation in new column

```
data_newer = [[99,3,12,4,63,55,87,-1]]

cols_new = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['1. FY21','2. FY22','3. FY23','4. New Column'],['Values','Sites']])

df_newer = pd.DataFrame(data_newer, columns = cols_new)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
# get unique names for columns at level 0
cols = df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()

# get first column
first_column = df.xs(cols[0], level=0, axis=1)

# get second column
second_column = df.xs(cols[1], level=0, axis=1)

# do the computation
d = first_column - second_column

# add column level
d = pd.concat({"4. New Column": d}, axis=1)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
  4. New Column       
          Sites Values
0            87     -1
```

---

Then add the column to the original dataframe:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, d], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  1. FY21        2. FY22        3. FY23        4. New Column       
    Sites Values   Sites Values   Sites Values         Sites Values
0      99      3      12      4      63     55            87     -1
```

---

EDIT: To add blank column to original dataframe:

```py
# create a blank dataframe
blank = pd.DataFrame(
    {("4. New Column", "Sites"): [np.nan], ("4. New Column", "Values"): [np.nan]}
)

# concatenate the blank dataframe with original df
df = pd.concat([df, blank], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  1. FY21        2. FY22        3. FY23        4. New Column       
    Sites Values   Sites Values   Sites Values         Sites Values
0      99      3      12      4      63     55           NaN    NaN
```

Or: create new columns:

```py
df.loc[:, ("4. New Column", "Sites")] = [np.nan] * len(df)
df.loc[:, ("4. New Column", "Values")] = [np.nan] * len(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! And how would you create just a blank new column?

Comment: @Sam Create a blank dataframe and concat it to the original one. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the unique values from level 1 and `join` to your original DataFrame to create the new columns with the same structure. Then use `at` to assign values:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["4. New Column"], df.columns.get_level_values(1).unique()])))
df.at[0, ("4. New Column","Values")] = 87
df.at[0, ("4. New Column","Sites")] = -1

>>> df
  1. FY21        2. FY22        3. FY23        4. New Column       
    Sites Values   Sites Values   Sites Values         Sites Values
0      99      3      12      4      63     55            -1     87
```